# Parsing JSON into TableView xcode 6.0.1, iOS8

Tags: json, xcode, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

There seems to be a dozen different ways to do this. This is the leanest I've come with, but am getting blank cells. So close!

MY holy grail next is to grab this all into a custom cell,  my first steps here.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var names = []

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://MYURL-here-which-pulls-down-the-JSON.json")
    let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    var err: NSError?

    let JSONResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as NSArray

    var _names: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for item: AnyObject in JSONResult {
        let name: NSString = item["name"] as NSString
        _names.addObject(name)
    }

    self.names = _names

    println(self.names)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    // THIS LINE IS THE ONE ***************************************************
    // NO VALUE TO DISPLAY ****************************************************

    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the cell yourself. You shouldn't do that.

Create a cell in the table view with a reuse identifier in Interface Builder and set the Cell Style to `Basic`. Then you can use code like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier",
                          indexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a label? Every UITableViewCell I've ever dealt with, even poorly created/handled as above, has a textLabel property..

Comment: @Mike You could be correct. The documentation is very unclear about this. I'll remove that part from the answer. But anyway it's not good to create a cell like this.

Comment: @edpotter You shouldn't name it Basic but set the *Style* to basic. Give it any identifier you want and replace `reuseIdentifier` in my *example* with your identifier.

Comment: Sorry my mistake there!  Got too excited - a possible solution!  This is what I did:  Ok I added a tableCell. Style to "Basic". Named it "MyCell". Then added this line of code.   let cell: UITableViewCell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell",
            indexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell  But I'm getting this error: "Use of unresolved identifier dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"

Comment: @edpotter Sorry, I forgot half of the method call. Of course it must be `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...`

Comment: Ok, did that edit. Bug came back, had to use forIndexPath:indexpath, which compiled fine. But still blank rows. Doubled checked all. Thanks for your quick responses. I have to run out for an hour. Then back to hacking on this. Just so close!

Comment: Thanks, I leap frogged this block of code and went right to a Custom TableCell. Thanks for your input. Checked your answer as solved.